# Ajax action for multiple submit buttons

Tags: php, ajax, yii

i have three ajaxsubmit buttons as below

```
echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton(
                                        'Save', //the label
                                        CController::createUrl('healthInformation/saveData'), //the url = index if empty (or set to another controllerAction)
                                        array('update'=>'#healthData',),  // the ajax-options: display the response inside this div
                                        array('class'=>'adm-myButton','title'=>'Save','name'=>'save') //your htmlOptions
                                        );
echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton(
                                        'add', //the label
                                        CController::createUrl('healthInformation/saveData'),  //the url = index if empty (or set to another controllerAction)
                                        array('update'=>'#healthData',),  // the ajax-options: display the response inside this div
                                        array('class'=>'adm-myButton','title'=>'Save','name'=>'add') //your htmlOptions
                                        );
echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton(
                                        'delete', //the label
                                        CController::createUrl('healthInformation/saveData'),  //the url = index if empty (or set to another controllerAction)
                                        array('update'=>'#healthData',),  // the ajax-options: display the response inside this div
                                        array('class'=>'adm-myButton','title'=>'Save','name'=>'delete') //your htmlOptions
                                        );
```

and can i access only one action `saveData` as below

```
public function actionSaveData()
{
   if(isset($_POST['save']))
   {
   }
  if(isset($_POST['add']))
   {
   }
 if(isset($_POST['delete']))
   {
   }
$this->renderPartial('');
}
```

or else have to access different actions for different ajaxsubmitbuttons.
please any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is very confusing. You should make an effort in rewriting it to make it more comprehensible, add any relevant code etc. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way  is using   button with different name

```
<?= Html::submitButton('Save',[ 'name'=>'save', 'value' => 'view', 'class' => 'btn btn-default',]) ?>
<?= Html::submitButton('Save&Next',[ 'name'=>'save_next', 'value' => 'print', 'class' => 'btn btn-default',]) ?>
<?= Html::submitButton('Delete',[ 'name'=>'delete', 'value' => 'print', 'class' => 'btn btn-default',]) ?>
....
```

then in your action

```
public function actionYourAction()
{
    if (isset($_POST['save')) { // or if you are using GET isset($_GET['save')
       // perform save code
       .....
       return;

   if (isset($_POST['save_next'])) {
       // perform save  & next code
       return;
    }
   if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
       // perform delete code
       return;
    }

    ......

}
```

Comment: is it same for ajaxsubmitbutton. i.e can multiple ajaxsubmitbutton can access through one action as same as you shown with names using post or get methods

Comment: This is only based  on a normal  Yii2 html helper  ..and php  code  but obviously you can do the same in several way .. using the client/server method you prefer ..

Comment: I have read you question  .. but  i can't understand your need .. you have already 3 button with different name .. and an action that check for the button click .. so  what your problem... you have error? .. don't work?.. wrong work? ..

Comment: don't work. they are three ajaxsubmitbuttons cant accessing one action